# How to include an articles in the WHMCS custom page?

Tags: whmcs

I would like to create a WHMCS custom page and then include a designated article in this page, is this possible?

I've created custom pages by [official documents](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/), but I don't know how to include articles.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: In your page, add link https : / / mywebserver.com/cart.php?a=add&pid=65 , where 65 ist the required product ID to be added in the Cart.

Comment: @houssam This doesn't seem to answer my question, I need to include an article in the custom page. This may need to be obtained by querying the database, but I don't know how to do that. Can you help? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lorrian1996 in the link that you have provided, see `Capsule::table('tblclients') `, to fetch products from DB , use `Capsule::table('tblproducts') ` or `getProductInfo` method https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getproducts/ then send them to the template

Comment: @houssam I need to include a knowledge article, not a product oh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must make join between :
  `tblknowledgebase , tblknowledgebasecats , tblknowledgebaselinks , tblknowledgebasetags`.
- See :https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/db-interaction/

your Template :

```
<!-- C:\xampp\htdocs\my\templates\redo\my_page.tpl-->
{foreach $arr as $elem}
<div>{$elem.title}</div>
<div>{$elem.article}</div>
<div>{$elem.views}</div>
{/foreach}
```

Your Page :

```
<?php
// file : ROOTDIR / my_page.php
use WHMCS\ClientArea;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

define('CLIENTAREA', true);

require_once  __DIR__ . '/init.php';
require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/dbfunctions.php');
//require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/functions.php');
//require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/clientfunctions.php');
//require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/modulefunctions.php');

$ca = new ClientArea();
$ca->setPageTitle('My Page');
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php', Lang::trans('globalsystemname'));
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('my_page.php', 'This is my page');
$ca->initPage();
//$ca->requireLogin(); // Uncomment this line to require a login to access this page
// To assign variables to the template system use the following syntax.
// These can then be referenced using {$variablename} in the template.

$knowledgebase=array();
//https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/db-interaction/
//$res=select_query('tblknowledgebase','*',array());
$res=full_query('SELECT * FROM tblknowledgebase');
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $knowledgebase[]=$data;
    var_dump($data);
}
// You must write   
//tblknowledgebase , tblknowledgebasecats , tblknowledgebaselinks , tblknowledgebasetags
file_put_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/my_website/sss.txt",var_export($knowledgebase,true),FILE_APPEND);

$ca->assign('arr', $knowledgebase); // $arr will be used in template.
$ca->assign('pagetype',redo);
// Check login status
//Menu::addContext();
$ca->setTemplate('my_page'); // without .tpl
$ca->output();
 ?>
```